# makefile not working

Tags: makefile

I am learning Linux module programming. I work on Ubuntu 12.04. I made a module, namely `start.c`, and saved it in `home/documents/module_prog`.

Then I made the following makefile (I am not acquainted with makefiles so I just did what the tutorial told me to):

```
obj-m += start.o

KDIR = /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-31-generic-pae

all:
    make -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.ko *.mod.* *.symvers *.order
```

But, now when I type make in the terminal, a message is displayed which says

```
  make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

Please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Do you have a file called `all` in your working directory?

Comment: Since you're on Linux, what happens if you use `make -B`?  This assumes everything is out of date and should execute the command, even if you have a file or directory called `all`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the commands for a make target are intended with a tab, not spaces. I.e.

```
all:
<tab>make -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
```

Otherwise the `all` target will be empty, and thus nothing is to be done.

Comment: Missing the tab would be invalid makefile syntax, and should generate a "missing separator" error, rather than what the OP is seeing.

Comment: If I copy the above Makefile into my Ubuntu 12.04 installation, it complains about missing separator on line 9 (the clean). If I fix that but leave the spaces in line 6, there are no errors but exactly the message avinash mentioned.

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right track then.  I'm surprised it lets you get away with that.

Comment: It probably considers the `SUBDIRS=$(PWD)` part as an assignment. At least if you remove the `=` you get the warning.

Comment: Rather astonishingly, if you add `$(info $(origin make -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS))` to the makefile, you'll see that a variable of that name has indeed been assigned to.